# On iOS, are 0x0000000000000026, 0x000000000000001c, 0x000000000000005a examples of tagged pointers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, lldb

On iOS 11, when I intentionally create objects which would turn out to be tagged pointers, they start with 0xB, instead of the 0x0000000000000026, 0x000000000000001c, 0x000000000000005a values that are showing up in my crash reports as invalid addresses.  I think these are likely tagged pointers, but they aren't formatted like tagged pointers that I see in the debugger.

What about 0x0000000000000010, 0x0000000000000020, 0x0000000000000030 ?  They all have a trailing 0, but they sure look suspiciously small to be real pointers.

Comment: You probably want to give a bit more context, with a bit of code, examples of where you see that (including logs and/or screenshots)... From what I understand, tagged pointers have 1 as their least significant bit (i.e., they're odd).

Answer (score 1):

The implementation details of tagged pointers changes from release to release and architecture to architecture.    With that said, those really don't look like tagged pointers.

What is most likely is that some piece of code is dereferencing into a struct or object that is unexpectedly NULL or nil.

Run this code:

```
struct bob {
    void *a;
    void *b;
    void *c;
    char d[42];
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct bob *fred = NULL;

    fred->d[2] = 'q';
    return 0;
}
```

You'll get this crash (on x86_64): `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1a)`

That is, it is trying to dereference through 0x0.   So, more likely than not, you have a struct/object reference that is NULL and your code is trying to dereference an element or instance variable that is offset by the hex #s you listed from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks.  So, if I understand you correctly, when I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000030` in crashlytics with a stack trace like `0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1838697f4 objc_object::release() + 16
1  Security                       0x18531b6b4 SecCertificateDestroy + 208 2  CoreFoundation                 0x18463cc3c _CFRelease + 216
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1845611b4 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 140` it has something to do with possibly a null pointer somewhere in the security certificate?

Comment: That would be a reasonable analysis, yes.